# My code gets an argument error, expecting 1 but got 0 - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mismatch

I've got this code with a variable of platform, which I'm trying to link with the actual object of Platform in my .fla file but I get this error when I run it; ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Code(). Expected 1, got 0. In my output window.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class Code extends MovieClip {

    var charSpeed:int = 0;
    var velocity:int = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 1;
    var Jump:Boolean = false;


    public function startGame(){
         stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyDown);
         stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyUp);
         stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
     }

    private var platform:Platform;

    public function Code(value:Platform) {
        platform = value;
    }

    function checkKeyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            charSpeed -= 10;
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            charSpeed += 10;
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            if(!Jump){
                velocity -= 14;
                Jump = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function checkKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            charSpeed = 0;
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            charSpeed = 0;
        }
    }

    function loop(evt:Event){
        player.x = velocity;
        if (player.x < 0){
             player.x = 0;
        }
        if (player.x > 550){
             player.x = 550;
        }

        velocity += gravity;

        var Platform:Array = new Array(platform)


        if (!Platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)){
            player.y += velocity;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (Platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)){
                player.y--;
                velocity = 0;
                Jump = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The as3 file name is Code, and the fla file name is Game. My objective is to get my player to move around on the platform using the arrow keys. The linkage of my platform is "Platform". If anyone could help that would be great

Answer (score 2):

The `Code(value:Platform)` constructor is expecting an argument of type `Platform`, but it seems your are invoking code with out passing 'Platform'. you need to pass the 'Platform' argument when ever you are creating code Object

Comment: oh okay, um would you be able to help with that haha?

Comment: just create Platform Object and pass it where ever you are calling code constructor

Comment: or if it is not required change it to have default value like so: `Code(value:Platform = null)` - of course if your class needs the `Platform` later you need to have a method to set it.